# Arduino IDE installation Problems

Tags: arduino-ide

When installing the IDE there are many "Unable to open *.DLL", errors. I check "ignore errors" and the IDE installed. Now when selecting the correct port and  board the blink sketch is uploaded and several ATK 500 errors result. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the IDE several time, with repeated results.

Answer (score 1):

You should check to make sure that your Java installation is up to date. It would also be best to make sure that you're bit types between the Java environment and the Arduino IDE are the same(32bit with 32bit, 64bit with 64bit). If this does not work, you should post your actual errors so we can help more :)

Comment: I updated my Java and that solved the problem. I appreciate your help Brad.